# I'm trying to identify a book, where the main character (a private detective, I believe) speaks mostly in e-prime

Tags: story-identification

Many years ago, I read a sci-fi novella, which remains in my memory mostly due to the main character speaking in [e-prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Prime) (the book was written in non-e-prime English besides the dialogue with the main character).

Is anyone here able to help me identify this book?

Comment: Can you clarify which of the two titles in the accepted answer were correct?

Comment: I think I accepted by accident - it's neither of those two afaik

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia lists two novels that David Gerrold wrote in e-prime:

- *[Under the Eye of God](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055329010X)*
- *[A Covenant of Justice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055356188X)*

Both seem to be out of print.

Comment: I think those novels are written entirely in e-prime. The book that I am looking for has the main character speaking in e-prime, while the book itself is not written in the style.

Comment: +1 if you can reword my last sentence in e-prime...

Comment: "My search has not revealed any current editions of either book" ;)

Comment: After a bit of research, my suspicion is that it was written by Robert Anton Wilson, but I can't find anything concrete to back it up, other than the facts that 1. He is a member of the General Semantics movement 2. He has talked and written about e-prime extensively 3. He mentioned writing a detective short story at an e-prime conference.  But the exact name of it eludes me...

Answer (score 3):

Is it in [Coincidance : A Head Test by Robert Anton Wilson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1561840041)?  Or maybe it's Boiling Creek: The G.S. Detective, Part II by Paul Dennithorne Johnston.

Comment: Which one of these got the accept?

Comment: @Pureferret: Beats me, although the first does not fit the description in that reviews indicate the entire book is written in e-prime, not just dialogue. Of course, the excerpts that I find of the latter (There's a Google Books version) don't seem to have any form of "to be" in them either...

Answer (score 0):

Is it Kiln People by David Brin?

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you add a brief description of this work so that we can learn a bit more about whether this story is in fact the one the OP is looking for?  Thanks

Comment: I believe you incorrectly identified *Kil'n People* by David Brin as the searched-for book. The first sentence of the first chapter, thought by the protagonist, begins with the word "it's", a contraction of "it is". After less than five seconds of browsing I found the sentence "The Wammaker job is done." on page 46, spoken directly by the protagonist. The latter would have appeared as something like "I have completed the Wammaker job." in e-prime. (I find it cumbersome to construct language in e-prime.)